# Different encoding issue

Tags: android, ajax, encoding, character-encoding

I'm writing an android app that implements a web server that sends pages containing text messages.
By client side I developed a web interface. This interface contains some DIVs that are filled using ajax and in particular with this functions that gets a page and put it into a specified div:

```
function getElementFromId(myElement) {
    var elem;
    if(document.getElementById)
        elem = document.getElementById(myElement);
    else
        elem = document.all[myElement];
    return elem;
}


function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    var XHR = null, browser = navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase();
    if(typeof(XMLHttpRequest) == "function" || typeof(XMLHttpRequest) == "object")
    XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if(window.ActiveXObject && browser.indexOf("MSIE 4") < 0) {
    if(browser.indexOf("MSIE 5") < 0)
    XHR = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    else
    XHR = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return XHR;
}


function pageInDiv(nomeFile,divId) {
  var ajax = getXMLHttpRequest(), elem = getElementFromId(divId),
  usaLink = true; 
  if(ajax) {
    usaLink = false;
    ajax.open("get", nomeFile, true);
    //ajax.setRequestHeader("connection", "close");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(ajax.readyState == 4) {
       if(ajax.status == 200)
         elem.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        else 
         elem.innerHTML += "Error: " + statusText[ajax.status];
      } 
    }
    ajax.send(null);
  }  
  return usaLink;
}
```

Now there's the problem! When I call `pageInDiv("pageWithText.html",myDiv)` the div is filled correctly, except for accented caracters. If the text contains àèìòù, the div will contain strange symbols, but (this is the strangest thing) if I open the page `http://.../pageWithText.html` directly in the browser it appears perfectly!

What's the problem? Thank you in advice

**Update**

This a piece of the web interface code:

`<body onLoad=" pageInDiv('conversations.html', 'conversations');>`

And this is the code of conversations.html:

```
<div id="conversations" class="list">
<div id="main">
<div id="msgTitle">Io</div>
<div id="message"><div id="img">
<img class="convimg" src="contactphoto_8259.jpg"></div>
<div id="text">������</div></div><div id="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me the code from your "web interface"? I mean the page that get filled with the data you collect from your ajax asynch call. I think the encoding problems is there. Maybe when you open the filled page with your web browser you get the default web browser encoding and that solve temporarly your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to include the following code in the html page where you have these encoding problems

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
...
</head>
```

If this encoding it's not working (I doubt it) you can try with different code from [this](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html) page.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer! I solved using this charset (for english, italian, spanish... etc languages)..:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

Comment: I'm glad I was useful but I still wondering why it's not working with utf-8. It should work also with the italian accent.